# Did Rory gain incredible fighting power?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode "The Big Bang", Rory had guarded the Pandorica for such a long time that he was called the Last Centurion. Stories said that Rory protected the Pandorica from many serious dangers.

And, in the episode "A Good Man Goes to War", Rory broke into a Cyberman flagship and threatened the Cybermen. As an intruder I think Rory must have defeated a lot of Cybermen before he came to the control room? (By the way, when the ships exploded outside the Cyberman flagship, did the Doctor do that?)

So did Rory gain incredible fighting power through out the time guarding the Pandorica?

Answer (score 18):

More specifically, I think he gained incredible fighting *experience*, *skill*, and *confidence*.

It's made clear in the episode [*Day of the Moon*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Day_of_the_Moon) that Rory still has some if not all of his memories of protecting the Pandorica ([transcript here](http://jpgr.livejournal.com/118715.html)):

> **DOCTOR:** Personal question.
>
> **RORY:** Seriously? You?
>
> **DOCTOR:** Do you ever remember it? 2,000 years, waiting for Amy? The Last Centurion?
>
> **RORY:** No.
>
> **DOCTOR:** Are you lying?
>
> **RORY:** Course I'm lying.
>
> **DOCTOR:** Course you are. Not the sort of thing anyone forgets.
>
> **RORY:** But I don't remember it all the time. It's like there's… a door in my head. I can keep it shut.

Imagine having *nearly 2 millennia* to practice and hone your fighting skills. Even if you only remember a fraction of it, you'd practically be a killing machine.

Comment: +1 exactly so.  The Legions were already the most disciplined and capable fighting force of their time, the thought of a Centurion with two millenia of practice is... the kind of scary guy that David Weber ends up writing novels about.

Comment: But who says that he practiced for two millennia? He probably spent most of the time waiting.

Comment: @TillB: In the museum there was a recount of the Last Centurian that mentioned him protecting the Pandorica throughout the ages from various threats, so he wasn't just waiting.

Comment: True. But still I think that at least 95% of his time was rather boring.

Comment: 99% of modern military life is boring routine.  The 1% of sheer howling terror?  Shapes people like those Rambo was based off of.  An average infantry career is less than 10 years.  Imagine Rambo, with 2 millennia of practice instead of 1 war.  Sure, Rory didn't start off anything like Rambo, but that experience would have closed the gap within the first century.

Comment: @Jeff Also recall his answer to the Doctor's question as to how he stayed out of trouble: "*Unsuccessfully*"